# How can I escape the \s (space char) from a string?

Tags: java, regex

What I need is to escape each word in a string and escape each special char like: !,?._'@.   What I've tried is this:

```
public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[!|,|?|.|_|'|@]");
        String a = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        String[] part = pat.split(a);
        System.out.println(part.length);
        for(String p: part)
           System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

While this does escape the special characters, I can't manage to find a way to have the regex match the spaces between each word. 
Also, I've tried using `\s` and `\\s` after the regex.

For input like: `The dog is a very lazy dog, isn't he?`
output should be:

```
The  
dog  
is  
a  
very  
lazy  
dog  
isn  
t  
he
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[..]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which describes range for single character, not two characters (we can allow repetition of characters with quantifiers like `+` `*` `{nim,max}` but that is not the case here).

Also you don't need to use `|` inside `[..]` because there it is simple character, not OR operator. So `[a|b]` doesn't mean `a` OR `b`, it represents characters `a` `|` `b` (so any repetition of `|` like `|c` will represent another `|` and `c`).

Based on example you provided, you may be looking for:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[!,?._'@\\s]+");
```

or since this may be more readable

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([!,?._'@]|\\s)+");
```

You would need to use `OR` operator `|` outside of `[..]` and write `\s` as `"\\s` since `\` is also special character in String literals (it can be used for instance to create tab character `\t`) so it requires escaping.

I wrapped entire expression with `(..)` to create group which can represent all your delimiters. This allowed me to use `+` (quantifier representing "one or more occurrences") so now you regex can see `,.` as single delimiter for split, which will ensure one split on entire expression of few continuous delimiter, rather then splitting on each of them separately. So instead of `"a,.b"` -> `["a, "", "b"]` now we will get `["a", "b"]`

Comment: I think you're right about the "|" character.  But this still doesn't escape each space in the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "escape each space in the string"? Can you update your question and post your input and expected results?

Comment: @MinaF Let me know if edited version worked for you. Will try to add explanation if it does.